# How do you keep running count of aws spot fleet (request and maintain) request instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ec2-spot-market

How can I get a running count of total number of spot fleet instances?
If the target capacity is 5 instances and sometime after if 2 of them somehow terminates and aws spot fleet automatically relaunch 2 instances to sustain the target capacity and I want to keep count of total instances launched as being 7 ( 5 target + 2 new instances because 2 of them terminated)

I can use this command to get the index value:

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-launch-index
```

However, once the spot fleet is met and if one of the instances terminates for some reason, the spot fleet will relaunch another instance automatically to fulfill the TargetCapacity, but the launch index will revert to "0" vs incrementing by 1 from the very last number assigned.

thanks!

Comment: We definitely need something similar to `ami-launch-index`, any time a fleet launches and instance that number should increment.